# why functions representation as dynamic symbols is not consistent (RH4, Solaris10 give different results)

Tags: gcc, linker, linker-errors, libcurl, ld

While trying to link functions from shared objects (libcurl.so), I'm getting 'undefined reference to `Curl_base64_decode''.  this only happens when compiling libcurl on RH4, but when I do it on solaris10 I get no errors.

it looks like in solaris 10 the functions are dynamic and on RH4 not.

```
Solaris10:
-bash-3.2$  nm -D libcurl.so | grep Curl_base
url_base64_decode
Curl_base64_encode

RH4:
-bash-3.2$  nm -D libcurl.so | grep Curl_base
*no results
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Redhat version was probably simply linked to hide internal symbols and the Solaris version wasn't. Like building with ./configure --enable-symbol-hiding.